# Duvida Sistema Simples Escolar

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, login

Bom estou fazendo um trabalho para faculdade, já estou no meio do caminho,  porém para fazer a parte final preciso:

- O professor pode cadastrar um pdf/imagem, na área dele.
- E o aluno na página dele consegue ver/baixar esse anexo.

O que tenho ate agora salva somente imagens.

O form para gravar o anexo.

```
<form action="gravar.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <label for="imagem">Imagem:</label> 
    <input type="file" name="imagem"/> <br/> 
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar"/>
</form>
```

E a parte para gravar a Imagem no banco de dados.

```
<?php 
$imagem = $_FILES["imagem"];
$host = "localhost";
$username = "root"; 
$password = ""; 
$db = "sistema"; 

if ($imagem != NULL) { 
    $nomeFinal = time().'.jpg'; 
    if (move_uploaded_file($imagem['tmp_name'], $nomeFinal)) { 
        $tamanhoImg = filesize($nomeFinal);
        $mysqlImg = addslashes(fread(fopen($nomeFinal, "r"), $tamanhoImg));

        mysql_connect($host,$username,$password) or die("Impossível Conectar"); 
        @mysql_select_db($db) or die("Impossível Conectar"); 
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO anexo (PES_IMG) VALUES ('$mysqlImg')") or die("O sistema não foi capaz de executar a query"); 

        unlink($nomeFinal);
        header("location:exibir.php");
    }
} else { 
    echo "Você não realizou o upload de forma satisfatória."; 
} 
?>
```

E aqui eu exibo a imagem gravada, num PHP:

```
<?php 
$host = "localhost"; 
$username = "root"; 
$password = ""; 
$db = "sistema"; 

mysql_connect($host,$username,$password) or die("Impossível conectar ao banco."); 
@mysql_select_db($db) or die("Impossível conectar ao banco"); 

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM anexo") or die("Impossível executar a query"); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) { 
    echo "<img src='getImagem.php?PicNum=$row->PES_ID' \">"; 
} 

?>
```

Mas o que eu gostaria era de mostrar esse anexo somente quando o aluno na área dele clicasse no link "anexo" e ele veria somente o anexo daquele trabalho e não de todos os outros.

Comment: Código mal indentado é a raiz de muitos males... Aqui um tutorial sobre como fazer isso corretamente e que aparece na primeira página do google: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NfS4HpRZciA

Answer (score 1):

Para guardar um arquivo em banco de dados e poder fazer o download depois, é necessário guardar o mimetype do arquivo, nome, tamanho, etc.

Para isso é necessário criar uma tabela da seguinte maneira

```
CREATE TABLE upload (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    type VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    size INT NOT NULL,
    content MEDIUMBLOB NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

O tipo `MEDIUMBLOB` até 16 megabytes mais ou menos, porem existem os tipos a seguir que devem ser usados de acordo com sua necessidade.

- TINYBLOB
- BLOB
- MEDIUMBLOB
- LONGBLOB

Para recuperar as informações do arquivo que está sendo feito o upload existe a variável global `$_FILES` que possui as seguintes informações:

```
// O nome original do arquivo 
$_FILES['userfile']['name'];

// O mimetype do arquivo. Esta informação é dada pelo browser do usuário.
// Por exemplo para uma imagem JPG seria "image/jpg"
$_FILES['userfile']['type'];

// O tamanho da imagem em bytes.
$_FILES['userfile']['size'];

// O nome do arquivo temporário criado quando o servidor recebe a
// requisição, e armazena para que o arquivo possa ser trabalhado.
$_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];

// O código de erro associado ao arquivo, caso houver. 
$_FILES['userfile']['error'];
```

Para gravar no banco de dados basta criar o seguinte script

**salvar.php**

```
$host = "localhost";
$username = "root"; 
$password = ""; 
$db = "sistema";

mysql_connect($host,$username,$password) or die("Impossível conectar com o banco de dados."); 
mysql_select_db($db) or die("Não foi possível selecionar o banco de dados."); 

if (isset($_POST['upload']) && $_FILES['userfile']['size'] > 0) {
    $fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
    $tmpName  = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];

    $fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
    $content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
    $content = addslashes($content);
    fclose($fp);

    $query = "INSERT INTO upload (name, size, type, content ) VALUES ('$fileName', '$fileSize', '$fileType', '$content')";

    mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
}
mysql_close(); // Não esqueça de finalizar a conexão.
header("Location: listar.php");
exit(); // Sempre que quiser fazer algum redirecionamento, finalize o script para evitar erros no envio de cabeçalho.
```

Crie um página para listar os arquivos para o usuário clicar nos links e fazer o download.

**listar.php**

```
<?php

$host = "localhost";
$username = "root"; 
$password = ""; 
$db = "sistema";

mysql_connect($host,$username,$password) or die("Impossível conectar com o banco de dados."); 
mysql_select_db($db) or die("Não foi possível selecionar o banco de dados."); 

?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Arquivos</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php

    $query = "SELECT id, name FROM upload";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
        echo "Database is empty <br>";
    } else {
        while (list($id, $name) = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo '<a href="download.php?id=' . $id . '">' . $name . '</a> <br>';
        }
    }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
<?php mysql_close() ?>
```

E o arquivo para permitir o download do arquivo

**download.php**

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $host = "localhost";
    $username = "root"; 
    $password = ""; 
    $db = "sistema";

    mysql_connect($host,$username,$password) or die("Impossível conectar com o banco de dados."); 
    mysql_select_db($db) or die("Não foi possível selecionar o banco de dados.");

    $id    = (int) $_GET['id'];
    $query = "SELECT name, type, size, content FROM upload WHERE id = '$id'";

    $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
    list($name, $type, $size, $content) = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    header("Content-length: $size");
    header("Content-type: $type");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name");

    echo $content;

    mysql_close();
    exit();
}
```

Esse exemplo é usado para guardar arquivos no banco de dados, mas você pode guardar a imagem real no servidor e armazenar no banco de dados apenas o nome da imagem para download, assim não seria necessário o arquivo `download.php` e seus arquivos ficariam da seguinte maneira:

**salvar.php**

O campo anexo na tabela do banco de dados guarda agora só o nome do arquivo.

```
$host = "localhost";
$username = "root"; 
$password = ""; 
$db = "sistema";

mysql_connect($host,$username,$password) or die("Impossível conectar com o banco de dados."); 
mysql_select_db($db) or die("Não foi possível selecionar o banco de dados."); 

if (isset($_POST['upload']) && $_FILES['userfile']['size'] > 0) {
    $fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
    $tmpName  = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];

    $pasta = __DIR__ . '/';
    $nomeFinal = time().'.jpg'; 
    if (move_uploaded_file($imagem['tmp_name'], $pasta . $nomeFinal)) { 
        $query = "INSERT INTO upload (anexo) VALUES ('$nomeFinal')";
        mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
    }
}
mysql_close(); // Não esqueça de finalizar a conexão.
header("Location: listar.php");
exit(); // Sempre que quiser fazer algum redirecionamento, finalize o script para evitar erros no envio de cabeçalho.
```

**listar.php**

```
<?php

$host = "localhost";
$username = "root"; 
$password = ""; 
$db = "sistema";

mysql_connect($host,$username,$password) or die("Impossível conectar com o banco de dados."); 
mysql_select_db($db) or die("Não foi possível selecionar o banco de dados."); 

?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Arquivos</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php

    $query = "SELECT id, anexo FROM upload";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
        echo "Database is empty <br>";
    } else {
        while (list($id, $anexo) = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo '<a href="caminho/da/pasta/' . $anexo . '" target="_blank">' . $anexo . '</a> <br>';
        }
    }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
<?php mysql_close() ?>
```

Comment: valeu amigo , ja me ajudou bastante =)